# mysql import csv "error2 no such file or directory"

Tags: python, mysql, csv, import

I want to import a csv file to mysql.here are my code.
I created an empty table called Sale_data and I make sure that the columns and data types are correct.

```
CREATE TABLE Sales_data(
Rank_number integer,
Name varchar(100),
Platform varchar(100),
Year int,
Genre varchar(100),
Publisher varchar(100),
NA_Sales float,
EU_Sales float,
JP_Sales float,
Other_Sales float,
Global_Sales float);
```

I also make sure the local_infile is on.

```
Show variables like "local_infile";
set global local_infile = 1;
```

my schema called 'book'

```
load data local infile 'D:/R_file/vgsales'
into table book.sales_data
character set 'utf8'
fields terminated by ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
ignore 1 rows;
```

I already search through lot of advices and tried different ways but it still pop up the  error 2 no such file or directory. below is the ways I try to make it work:

1.the csv file 'vgsales' which i want to import into my table.i checked the directory is correct and no typo. i tried different slash such as "\","//","" but they all failed.

2. I went into the my.ini file, find the "secure-file-pri" first time I changed like secure-file-priv="". I leave it empty and restart mysql but still not work
   second time I changed the path like secure-file-priv="D:\R_file". and it still not work.

I use this line of code SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%secure%' to see the path
and the value shows D:\R_file\

So I literally tried everything. the error 2 no such file or directory pop up every time.
it kind of drives me crazy.
hopefully someone can address my problem.
ps: I encountered similar question with jupyter notebook, it is the same error but i can solve it by create the py file under the folder with the csv file I want to import. this problem can be solved.

address this "error 2 no such file or directory" problem

Comment: also,  load data local infile statement, i tried drop the term 'local',it didnt work either.

Comment: Please post full error. It can contain more info to where it was exactly encoutered

Comment: no, I did try full extension (vgsales.csv) but still. It is the permission that trigger the error

Answer (score 0):

silly me! The problem is the permission to access the file. I open mysql workbench by the administrator and it complete worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).